# Boost on laptop

Tags: boost

How to manage the Boost set using laptop (with Windows)?

It seems that the Boost Application for Windows 10 earlier available on Microsoft Store is no longer working:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/lego-boost/9nzn5q1ck1qk

I tried BlueStack emulator of Android to use mobile version of Boost Application. It installs properly, but now the problem is that the emulator doesn't support Bluetooth connection:
https://support.bluestacks.com/hc/en-us/articles/360061235612-Bluetooth-support-on-BlueStacks-5

Are you able to somehow use your laptop to code and run Boost?

Comment: Sorry to hear that windows is no longer supported. Feels like a mistake